# Discord.js - How to allow command in specific channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a custom bot for Discord and I need some help.

I have the following code:

```
if(command === 'sino') {
if (msg.channel.id === '761500739842506774') {
msg.react("")
msg.channel.send("", { 
files: ["https://image.png"], });
}}
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong with the if.

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look wrong, so check your channel id. Also please specify what isn't working.

Comment: I tried again and the first code has worked, I don't know what happened... thank you :)